# Copying rows; avoid rows with empty cells on column G

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running a VBA code to copy values of columns to another sheet.

Samples is on this image:[image: Sample]

The Code i have is :

```
inputWS4.Range("G2:G" & LastRowFLBlue).Copy outputWS.Range("B" & LastRowGeovera + (lastRowUniversal - 2) + LastRowCitizens)
```

This code will copy column G to the last row on my "outputWS" sheet which has already has data from other sheets(Geovera,Universal & Citizens).

The problem with the code is that it will also copy the blank cells and i do not want to do that.

Also i want to copy values from column D and P, but i want to avoid these values if the cell on column G for that row is empty. this will avoid that the word "TOTAL" on column p gets copied over as well.

Please help!

PS my lastrow for this sheet is :

```
LastRowFLBlue = inputWS4.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: The code ive tried is the one posted. i have no clue on how to avoid blank cells. ive been researching to no luck so far

Comment: Your question is not very clear, this is not difficult to do, you just need to use a `for loop` and use some `if`s inside the loop to filter data being copied

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm trying to copy the values on the column and avoid copying the blank cells. Then for d & p I want to copy the exact rows I copied from column G.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide rows with blanks by by looping through column G and hiding the whole row if you find a blank.

```
If Len(yourcell)=0 Then EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Then copy/paste visible cells in the column you want using

```
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Comment: im trying : 

 `If Len(inputWS4.Range("G2:G" & LastRowFLBlue)) = 0 Then EntireRow.Hidden = True
    inputWS4.Range("G2:G" & LastRowFLBlue).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy inputWS4.Range("Q" & LastRowFLBlue)`

and a debug error highlight the code until "THEN" is showing. So im not getting to even hide the rows with blank value

Comment: That's because mine was an example not full code. you need to loop through your cell     Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Range("a1:a299")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In r
    If Len(c.text) = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c